# compare speed of recursion and exceptions - Python

Tags: python, performance, exception, recursion, compare

first of all i must say sorry for my bad english but im trying my best.

i have an exercise about compare speed of calculating factorials using recursion and exceptions in python.

I wrote a code:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

def standardFactorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * standardFactorial(n-1)

def factorialWithExceptions(n):
    if n == 1:
        raise MyException(1)
    try:
        factorialWithExceptions(n-1)
    except MyException as x:
        raise MyException(n * x.value)
```

run 10 000 times for factorial of 300 and i got results like:

```
recursion
1.233912572992267
exceptions
9.093736120994436
```

Can someone explain to me why the difference is so big?
exceptions in python are so slow? or what is the problem? building stack of exceptions?
Thanks for any reply.

Comment: In the second example, you're using recursion and exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are supposed to be for "exceptional" conditions.  Python's implemenation is supposed to be slightly lighter weight than Java's, which leads to pythonic approaches tending towards using exceptions more often than java ones (there's a motto: better to ask forgiveness than permission).  Even so, using exceptions for flow control is frowned upon in pretty much all languages because it makes it harder to reason about the code and also because there is a performance hit to create the exception, trap it, unwind all the bits, and continue on.

With that said, just for comparison, I tested the java equivalent (using BigInteger's because just using ints lead to nonsensical results for factorial(300).  The first time, I got really weird results that I'm going to have to look at, but updating code to do both in the same app and do some checking that hopefully ensures we don't get fake results due to optimizations etc.:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;


class BigIntegerHolder extends Exception
{
    public BigInteger bigInt;
    public BigIntegerHolder(BigInteger x) { this.bigInt = x; }
}

class Factorial
{

    public static BigInteger fact(int n)
    {
        if (n == 1)
            {
                return BigInteger.valueOf(1);
            }
        return fact(n-1).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(n));
    }



    public static void factExcept(int n) throws BigIntegerHolder
    {
        if (n == 1)
            {
                throw new BigIntegerHolder(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
            }
        try {
            factExcept(n-1);
        }
        catch (BigIntegerHolder ex)
            {
                throw new BigIntegerHolder( ex.bigInt.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(n)));
            }
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BigInteger realValue = fact(300);
        int count = 0;

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                try {
                factExcept(300);
                }
                catch (BigIntegerHolder ex)
                    {
                        if (realValue.equals(ex.bigInt))
                            {
                                count += 1;
                            }
                    }

            }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("We got it right " + count + " times in " + (end - start) + " ms");


       count = 0;
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
            {
                BigInteger x = fact(300);
                if (realValue.equals(x))
                    {
                        count += 1;
                    }
            }
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("We got it right " + count + " times in " + (end - start) + " ms");

    }
}
```

This outputs:

> We got it right 10000 times in 23708 ms
>
> We got it right 10000 times in 271 ms

(Indicating that in Java, doing it with exceptions is almost 100 times slower)